# Clickable space between layout elements

Tags: android, xml, layout, frontend

Im creating android app that is displaying over other apps

I need layout that contains two centered bars (linearlayout) that are filled with buttons, i need space between these bars, so user can click app below my overlay. How can i achieve this?

focus, clickable set to true or false for space and view

and

ConstrainLayout combinations

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onSpacerClicked(View view) {
// Handle the click event for the spacer
// You can put your logic here
```

}

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <!-- Top Bar -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/topBar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

        <!-- Buttons for the top bar -->
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 2"/>
        <!-- Add more buttons as needed -->

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Clickable Space -->
    <View
        android:id="@+id/clickableSpace"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/topBar"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:onClick="onSpacerClicked"/>

    <!-- Bottom Bar -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/clickableSpace"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

        <!-- Buttons for the bottom bar -->
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 3"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 4"/>
        <!-- Add more buttons as needed -->

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```